# Set PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH on MySql Connector/Net

Tags: c#, mysql, connector-net

As [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html) states,

> The length of a CHAR column is fixed to the length that you declare
>   when you create the table. The length can be any value from 0 to 255.
>   When CHAR values are stored, they are right-padded with spaces to the
>   specified length. When CHAR values are retrieved, trailing spaces are
>   removed unless the PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH SQL mode is enabled.

How to enable PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH flag in Connector/Net? (not ODBC)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented under [Server SQL Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html):

> To change the SQL mode at runtime, set the global or session [`sql_mode`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode) system variable using a [`SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/set-statement.html) statement:
>
> ```sql
> SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'modes';
> SET SESSION sql_mode = 'modes';
> ```
>
> Setting the `GLOBAL` variable requires the [`SUPER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) privilege and affects the operation of all clients that connect from that time on. Setting the `SESSION` variable affects only the current client. Each client can change its session [`sql_mode`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_mode) value at any time.

Therefore you want to execute a plain old SQL command along the following lines:

```sql
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH';
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround in case that you don't want to change the SQL mode is to TRIM previously the value, the reason is that CHAR types are fixed.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field1` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field2` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comb` varchar(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (concat(TRIM(`field2`),'test')) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```